# Is this use of va_copy undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, variadic-functions, c99, ansi-c

I made a function that prints pairs of keys and values, where the keys are **trusted compile time literal** strings which possibly can contain printf specifiers. Now my question is: is this function legal according to the c standard (like c99)? If not, can I do anything to conform?

```c
void pairs(char *message, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, message);

    char *key = va_arg(args, char *);
    if (key == NULL) {
        va_end(args);
        return;
     }

    while (key != NULL) {
        if (key[0] == '%') {
            int len = strlen(key);
            printf("%s=", &key[len + 1]);

            // Copy the current state of the va_list and pass it to vprintf
            va_list args2;
            va_copy(args2, args);
            vprintf(key, args2);
            va_end(args2);

            // Consume one argument assuming vprintf consumed one
            va_arg(args, char *);
        } else {
            // if no format assume it is a string
            fprintf(_log_stream, "%s=\"%s\"", key, va_arg(args, char *));
        }

        key = va_arg(args, char *);
        if (key == NULL)
            break;

        printf(", ");
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

It should work something like

```c
    pairs("This is a beautiful value",
            "%d\0hello", 10,
            "pass", user_var,
            "hello", "bye", NULL);
```

And it actually outputs correctly: `hello=10, pass="sus", hello="bye"`
So it works on my machine (using gcc). But again, is it compliant?

Edit:
I found https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variable-Arguments-Output.html

> Portability Note: **The value of the va_list pointer is undetermined after the call to vprintf**, so you must not use va_arg after you call vprintf. Instead, you should call va_end to retire the pointer from service. You can call va_start again and begin fetching the arguments from the start of the variable argument list. (Alternatively, you can use va_copy to make a copy of the va_list pointer before calling vfprintf.) Calling vprintf does not destroy the argument list of your function, merely the particular pointer that you passed to it.

Which is the reason why I use va_copy in the first place, but I am not sure if there is a way to get around that restriction.

Comment: When calling a variadic function you should always cast `NULL` to a pointer type: `(char *)NULL`.

Comment: There is no problem passing a partially used `va_list` and/or a `va_list` containing excess arguments to `vprintf`.

Comment: The initial `if (key == NULL)` statement seems to be redundant.

Comment: If you can legally call `vprintf(key, args);` then I don't see why you couldn't call `vprintf(key, args2);`. Are you wondering whether you can call `vprintf()` with a partially-consumed va_list?

Comment: Or are you wondering about the additional arguments that aren't consumed by the format string?

Comment: The "consume one argument" logic seems wrong because it assumes the next argument is a `char *`.

Comment: Extra arguments to printf functions are ignored. So the second issue is not a problem.

Comment: In practice I think it's likely to be safe to do this without making a copy at all, since `vprintf()` will consume the arguments needed by the format string. Unfortunately, the spec says that the state of `arg` is indeterminate after calling the `vXXX` functions. This would avoid the problem @IanAbbott points out.

Comment: @Barmar yes I was wondering if I can va_copy a partially used va_list.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes I just noticed. I put that in place because I read somewhere that vprintf doesn't guarantee anything about the va_list. Do you know any way to consume the arg properly?

Comment: You'd need to know the (default argument promoted) type of the argument being consumed.

Comment: Or you could let `vprintf` consume the original arguments rather than a copy.

Comment: Ignore my comment "Or you could let `vprintf` consume the original arguments rather than a copy." As pointed out by @nect in comments to my (deleted) answer, this is UB. They cited a portabiliity note in the GCC manual, but the corresponding reference in C17 is §7.16/3 "… The object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the **`va_arg`** macro with parameter `ap`, the value of `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the **`va_end`** macro prior to any further reference to `ap`."

Comment: If there was an alternative to `vprintf` that accepted a pointer to a `va_list`, that would work, as allowed by C17 footnote 257: "It is permitted to create a pointer to a **`va_list`** and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns.". Unfortunately, there is no such alternative function defined by the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this use of va_copy undefined behaviour?

No.

> is this function legal according to the c standard (like c99)?

No. The:

```
 key = va_arg(args, char *);
```

is undefined behavior. The next argument is `10`, which is an `int`.

(Also, technically, `NULL` is not a `char *`. `NULL` is either an `int` **or** `void *`, no one knows. It is also not valid for `NULL`. But, nowadays `NULL` is universally `(void *)0`, and on sane systems all pointers are the same size, bottom line if you use `char *` no one will notice. But if you want to be correct, the argument should be `(char *)NULL`.)

> If not, can I do anything to conform?

What you want to do in the way you want to do is not possible. You are not able to use `va_list` after `vprintf` has used it. After `vprintf` has used `va_list` you *have to* `va_end` it.

If you want to do that, you have to parse the format string yourself and get the types of arguments yourself and advance `va_list` yourself and either implement `vprintf` yourself or you could call it separately.

---

> can I do **anything**

Och yea, sure, totally. So let's implement a `pairs` as a variadic macro that just forwards to `printf`.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/facilities/overload.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PAIRS1_0()
#define PAIRS1_2(a, b)       " " a
#define PAIRS1_4(a, b, ...)  " " a  PAIRS1_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PAIRS1_6(a, b, ...)  " " a  PAIRS1_4(__VA_ARGS__)

#define PAIRS2_0()
#define PAIRS2_2(a, b)       b
#define PAIRS2_4(a, b, ...)  b, PAIRS2_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PAIRS2_6(a, b, ...)  b, PAIRS2_4(__VA_ARGS__)

#define pairs(pre, ...)  \
    printf(  \
        pre  \
        BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD(PAIRS1_, __VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__) \
        "\n",  \
        BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD(PAIRS2_, __VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__)  \
    )

int main() {
    pairs("This is a beautiful value",
        "hello=%d", 10,
        "hello=%s", "bye");
}
```

The call becomes a single `printf` with space joined arguments. The first overloaded macro joins the strings into one string, and then the second overloaded macro takes the second arguments. It is a simple shuffle to re-order arguments for `printf`.

But this is not satisfactory. You might delve into this more, by using `_Generic` to guess the format specifier. From the arguments, you can construct an array of "printers" that take `va_list` by a pointer. Not by value! You can only modify the "upper" function `va_list` by passing with a pointer. Then you can iterate over printers to print the values, one by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// printers for pairs

void pairs_int(va_list *va) {
    const int v = va_arg(*va, int);
    printf("%d", v);
}
void pairs_charp(va_list *va) {
    char *p = va_arg(*va, char *);
    printf("%s", p);
}

#define PRINTER(x)  \
    _Generic((x) \
    , int: &pairs_int  \
    , char *: &pairs_charp \
    )

typedef void (*printer_t)(va_list *va);

// the actual logic
void pairs_in(const char *pre, const printer_t printers[], ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, printers);
    fputs(pre, stdout);
    for (const printer_t *printer = printers; printer; printer++) {
        putchar(' ');
        fputs(va_arg(va, char*), stdout);
        putchar('=');
        (*printer)(&va);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    va_end(va);
    putchar('\n');
}

// Convert arguments into an array of printers
#define PRINTERS_0()
#define PRINTERS_2(a, b)       PRINTER(b)
#define PRINTERS_4(a, b, ...)  PRINTERS_2(a, b), PRINTERS_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PRINTERS_6(a, b, ...)  PRINTERS_2(a, b), PRINTERS_4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PRINTERS_N(_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...)  PRINTERS##N
#define PRINTERS(...)  PRINTERS_N(__VA_ARGS__,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1)(__VA_ARGS__)

// The entrypoint
#define pairs(pre, ...)  \
    pairs_in(pre, (const printer_t[]){ \
        PRINTERS(__VA_ARGS__), NULL, }\
        __VA_OPT__(,) \
        __VA_ARGS__ \
    )

int main() {
    pairs("This is a beautiful value",
        "value", 10,
        "hello", "bye");
}
```

Now you can expand this method, by for example including in the `"hello"` a format specifier like you wanted, and then extract it. For example `"%d\0hello"`, if the string starts with `%`, split it on `\0` and use the leading part for printing inside the printer. I think this is the interface you aimed for.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// printers for pairs
const char *_extract_fmt(const char *text, const char *def) {
        return text[0] == '%' ? text : def;
}

const char *_extract_name(const char *text) {
        return text[0] == '%' ? text + strlen(text) + 1 : text;
}

void pairs_int(const char *text, va_list *va) {
        const int v = va_arg(*va, int);
        printf(_extract_fmt(text, "%d"), v);
}
void pairs_charp(const char *text, va_list *va) {
        char *v = va_arg(*va, char *);
        printf(_extract_fmt(text, "%s"), v);
}

#define PRINTER(x) _Generic((x), int: &pairs_int, char *: &pairs_charp)

typedef void (*printer_t)(const char *text, va_list *va);

// the actual logic
void pairs_in(const char *pre, const printer_t printers[], ...) {
        va_list va;
        va_start(va, printers);
        fputs(pre, stdout);
        for (const printer_t *printer = printers; *printer; printer++) {
                putchar(' ');
                char *text = va_arg(va, char *);
                fputs(_extract_name(text), stdout);
                putchar('=');
                (*printer)(text, &va);
                fflush(stdout);
        }
        va_end(va);
        putchar('\n');
}

// Convert arguments into an array of printers
#define PRINTERS_0()
#define PRINTERS_2(a, b) PRINTER(b)
#define PRINTERS_4(a, b, ...) PRINTERS_2(a, b), PRINTERS_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PRINTERS_6(a, b, ...) PRINTERS_2(a, b), PRINTERS_4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PRINTERS_N(_6, _5, _4, _3, _2, _1, N, ...) PRINTERS##N
#define PRINTERS(...) PRINTERS_N(__VA_ARGS__, _6, _5, _4, _3, _2, _1)(__VA_ARGS__)

// The entrypoint
#define pairs(pre, ...) \
        pairs_in(pre, (const printer_t[]){ \
                          PRINTERS(__VA_ARGS__), \
                          NULL, \
                      } __VA_OPT__(, ) __VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
        pairs("This is a beautiful value", "%10d\0value", 10, "hello", "bye");
}
```

Or you can expand such a library and start supporting python format strings and so on, which is what I did with now dead [yio library](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/-/blob/master/src/yio/template/manip/manip.h?ref_type=heads#L58), as I do not have time for it.

Comment: thank you, I'll try to make the macro thing work with c99 :p

Comment: I think it should work. I think you can also include boost preprocessor in C99. I do not know how to BOOST_PP_FOREACH over two arguments at a time, that would simplify it, so I used BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD and written the overloads. If you do not want boost, then around `#define PRINTERS_N` shows how to overload a macro yourself. I can edit it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this use of va_copy undefined behaviour?

The `va_copy` is not itself undefined, nor is passing the copy to `vprintf`.  Nor is using `va_end` on it after the function returns -- that's required.

But ***this*** is a problem:

> ```
>             // Consume one argument assuming vprintf consumed one
>             va_arg(args, char *);
> ```

Generally speaking, you cannot consume a variable argument without knowing its (promoted) type, or close enough to that. Compatible types are interchangeable in this regard. Corresponding signed and unsigned integer types are interchangeable with each other here, provided that the actual value is representable in both.  Also, types `char *` and `void *` are interchangeable with each other here.  If the type specified to `va_arg` is not among those alternatives, or if there aren't any more variable arguments at all, then UB results from the `va_arg` call.

Some of your alternatives are:

- perform your own analysis to determine what type of argument to skip, or
- write `pairs` as a function-like macro instead of a *bona fide* function (with use of a large dose of macro magic), or
- reimagine the function to receive more or differently organized information that better serves your purposes.